# Get Top/Best Rated Product in Magento

Tags: magento

I want to best rated product on a magento homepage. I have product reviewing module configured on my site.

i have tried following this http://www.odino.org/84/retrieve-top-rated-products-in-magento

but am unable to get it working.

My homepage is formed my calling one block from the cms home page {{block type="page/html" template="page/html/home.phtml"}}

and i have tried putting the php code in home.phtml

The link i have posted asks to create a helper, but i don't know how to go about that, so what i did was wrote a normal function within the page and called it.

Any help would be seriously appreciated :)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this module from Inchoo, explained with all the required changes you need to make with screenshots. Hopefully this will be helpful

http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/bestseller-products-in-magento/

Comment: Hi jagageesh,

thanks for your help... but i dont need bestseller product, i need best rated... ie. any product which has four or five star rating